# Examples of Spring applications over Karaf

Tags: spring, apache-karaf

Are there publicly available examples of Spring applications in Karaf 2.2.x, in particular ones using `@Repository` and other Spring component annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Spring and Karaf you're most probably bound to Spring DM version 1.2.1 and therefore also probably also bound to Spring 2.5.6. You're probably better of switching to blueprint.